# How to get a website's HTML with runtime AJAX changes applied with Perl and Selenium?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, selenium, web-crawler

For websites that rely on Ajax or javascript to render data, how can I use WWW::Selenium to save the data? My following code was able to perform all the clicks and get to the correct webpage, however it did not save the data (I mean the list of all contests) because it is not in the html source code. I tried $sel->get_body_text() but it did not work either. Can you help me save the rendered data to a txt file or htm file? Thank you.

```
use WWW::Selenium;

open (FO, ">test.htm");
my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost",
                              port => 4444,
                              browser => "*firefox",
                              browser_url => "https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/",
                            );

$sel->start;
$sel->open("https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/");
$sel->click("all-switch");
$sel->click("completed");
print FO $sel->get_html_source();
print "Done\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I have not tried this!**

You should be able to use [`get_eval($script)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Selenium#sel-get_eval-script) to run some JavaScript that grabs the full current DOM for you. That's different from the page's body text, because the DOM is the current representation, and not what the browser parsed initially.

```
my $html = $sel->get_eval(q{document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML});
```

When I run that JS in my browser's console it gives me the full page's current representation. Here's a snippet that creates an empty `<div>`, then uses jQuery to add some text into it and afterwards uses the plain JS code from above to fetch the HTML of the full document and `alert` it. You'll see it contains the text we added.

```js
$('#foo').text("bar");
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. 
my $html = $sel->get_eval(q{window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML});
yields the same result as 
my $html=$sel->get_html_source();

Comment: Shame. I am going to try if I manage to install this stuff. Does the module work with the new version of Selenium? The one in the doc is deprecated.

Comment: Hi, simbabque, I figured it out eventually. It did not work because: even though $sel->click("all-switch") is called and is shown on the browser, the DOM is not updated. After I used $sel->get_eval() to evoke the event using Javascript, it worked! Thank you for helping me know using my $html = $sel->get_eval(q{document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML}) to save the DOM. It is a fun learning process and I have also self-figured out how to wait until the Ajax is fully loaded the DOM is fully presented. Thank you for your inspiration.

Comment: One of the most important skills in my opinion is to be able to read and understand documentation. That's not as easy as it sounds. I'm glad you learned something, instead of just getting an answer to copy. That's worth a lot more. :-) now another skill is impatience. So if that Ajax just pulls and adds some data, and that's the data you really want, just use lwp and grab it directly. Way faster. ;-)